# How do I get image by object id? (Django)

Tags: django, image

I'm trying to get images for an object filtered by the object's id, but for now, I don't even see any request to it in my MySQL database. The snippets of my code are below.

#### models.py:

```
class Media(models.Model):
   word = models.ForeignKey(Word, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   title = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

#### views.py:

```
class MediaListView(generic.ListView):
   model = Media
   template_name = 'dictionaty_web/index.html'
   context_object_name = 'images'

   def get_queryset(self):
       return Media.objects.filter(word=self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['pk'])
```

#### urls.py:

```
  urlpatterns = [
             path('languages/<int:pk>/', views.WordMapListView.as_view(), name='wordmaps'),
  ]

  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

#### index.html:

```
  {% for word in words %}
    <div class="col-sm text-center">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img scr="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ image.image.url }}">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ word.value }}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'dictionaty_web:detail' word.language.id word.word.id %}" class="stretched-link"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ok. This was dumb. I have a typo in my '<img src>' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Your urls.py is also important when serving images in django.

do you have imported in your urls.py the following code

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns=[
    path('url/', name_of_view, name = 'url_name'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                              document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hi! I have this in "urls.py" for the page where I want to see my images:

urlpatterns = [
      path('languages/<int:pk>/', views.WordMapListView.as_view(), name='wordmaps'),
]

However, I added the line you have suggested about MEDIA_URL (which I have already had in urls.py in my project folder), it did not help.